# SIGSEGV is blocked by default

Tags: segmentation-fault

I have an application:  "app-ctrl"
Process-id:  1000

I want to kill this process by sending signal SIGSEGV. ( Req. for simulation purpose)

[santosh@localhost ~]$ kill -11 1000

for the first time app-ctrl is killed. Now when its started again with following command:

[santosh@localhost ~]$ start app-ctrl

It gets new process id 2000.

Now if I want to kill it with command "kill -11 2000".  It does not work.

All other signal works like "kill -6 2000"  or "kill -9 2000" .  By doing debugging I found
by somehow SIGSEGV is blocked.  So I add following 3 statement inside our main code base:

```
sigemptyset (&x);

sigaddset(&x, SIGSEGV);

sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &x, NULL);
```

After adding above 3 lines "kill -11 " works all the time with new binary.
Every time "app-ctrl" is started it will execute above 3 statements.

Why SIGSEGV is blocked by default.  Is there any way to stop SIGSEGV from getting blocked ?